# How to Open a Google Chrome Pop-out Window via Windows Command Prompt

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, command-line

I'd like to put a .bat file on my desktop that opens my Twitch chat in a pop-out window instead of a regular Google Chrome window. The [pop-out window I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYXdY.jpg) has no header or tabs which makes it take up less space, and I'd prefer it to be in a pop-out window.

Using the URL for my Twitch chat, command would I use to achieve this?

I found [this](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension) link to a list of Google Chrome command line switches, but I can't seem to find anything related to pop-out windows.

Answer (score -1):

try this on cmd;

```
start chrome /new-window www.stackoverflow.com
```

it opens a new window with the link www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The new window is _not_ a pop-out window, but a standard one, and have standard header and tabs...